# How to search vector layer features in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I need to add a search bar that will search vector layer attribute features which are hosted by mapbox. I'm using the Mapbox GL JS API. I know this can be done fairly easily with Mapbox js/Leaflet. I'm totally stuck as to how to do the same in Mapbox GL JS. I want to search for a zip code, which corresponds to a feature attribute in my vector layer (please note, I don't wish to geocode an address or zip code. I am aware that there is a geocoder plugin for Mapbox GL. This is not what I'm looking for). I'm then hoping to update a html info panel with various feature values from the vector layer based on the matching search entry.

I need to know how to marry search functionality with the vector layer features served by Mapbox (This question specifically relates to Mapbox GL, not the older Mapbox JS library).